# How to disable a button when the state or the input value gets changed in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, onchange

I have a form which has a large number of inputs and update button. I am looking for the best way to disable the button unless one of the states or inputs get changed. I know about the way that having Boolean state variable to hold the button's disable/enable state. Then on change of the input field set value to the state variable name accordingly.

since i have a large number of states. I need to write a code which loop trough the nested object and compare.

I would appreciate your help

Comment: I do have but its a lot of code. not sure if you want to see it

Comment: I am trying to post it but there is character limitation. is there any other way I  can send it to you?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kxvr5gdf/

Comment: when you say "disable the button" do you mean, enable/disable the submit button depending on if the form fields are all filled out?

Comment: if even one of them filled I want the button gets enable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why the `boolean` approach would be bad.

Anyways, you could compare your previous model object with your current state using lodash [_.isEqual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3198202/5912765) function to check whether data has changed or not.

**UPDATE (snippet):**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    foo: '',
    bar: ''
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    const { foo, bar } = this.props;
    this.setState({ foo, bar });
  }
  
  hasChangedSinceInitialState = () => {
    const { foo, bar } = this.props;
        
    // here you could use lodash ._isEqual if you have an bigger object
    return (foo === this.state.foo && bar === this.state.bar);
  }
  
  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (<div>
      <div>Foo: <input type='text' name='foo' value={this.state.foo} onChange={this.handleInputChange} /></div>
      <div>Bar: <input type='text' name='bar' value={this.state.bar} onChange={this.handleInputChange} /></div>
      <button disabled={this.hasChangedSinceInitialState()}>Submit</button>
    </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App foo='oldFoo' bar='oldBar' />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/isEqual.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Sure. I've updated my answer with a snippet. Let me know if you have any questions about that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation and code correctly, then you are only interested in validating on certian variables in your component state.

You could achieve the desired validation behaviour by adding the following method to your component:

```
getCustomValidation() {

  // Extract a list for validation on only the state fields that are 
  // relevance to the form validation
  const fieldsToValidate = [
    "ppvLimit",
    "securityCode",
    "primaryPhone",
    "secondaryPhone",
    "email",
    "billingAddressLine1",
    "billingAddressLine2",
    "billingAddressCity",
    "billingAddressTerritoryCode",
    "billingAddressPostalCode",
    "contactAddressLine1",
    "contactAddressLine2",
    "contactAddressCity",
    "contactAddressTerritoryCode",
    "contactAddressPostalCode",
    "authorizedUser1",
    "authorizedUser2",
    "authorizedUser3",
    "authorizedUser4"
  ];

  // Iterate each field to check to determine if field is valid
  for(const fieldToValidate of fieldsToValidate) {

    // Extract value for current field
    const value = this.state[ fieldToValidate ]

    // If value is "truthy" then return valid (true)
    if( !!value ) {
      return true
    }
  }

  // If none of the validation fields are valid, return false
  return false;
}
```

To make use of this, you could update the Submit component in your render method as follows:

```
<Button primary disabled={ !this.getCustomValidation() } type="submit">
{ loading ? <div><LoadingIcon size="lg" /> Saving...</div> : "Update" }
</Button>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I used your logic in the code but when I am trying to console.log(getCustomValidation()) I am getting bunch of true and false before changing any fields.

Comment: Are you sure `getInitialState()` is being called correctly? If so `getCustomValidation()` should return false based on the initial states. This is likely due to `nextProps` passed externally via `componentWillReceiveProps`. Also note that `console.log(getCustomValidation())` is not correct - it should be `console.log(thisgetCustomValidation())`